# Multiple yaml cron schedules not working in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 2 cron schedules defined in Azure Devops but they are not both being respected.

```yaml
trigger: none

schedules:
  - cron: '0 */1 * * Mon-Sat'
    always: true
    displayName: Run Every hour Monday to Saturday
    branches:
      include:
        - beverly-hills-ops/matt.oconnor/904176-reactive

  - cron: '0 0-11,16-23 * * Tue-Wed'
    always: true
    displayName: Run Every hour on Tuesday and Wednesday except 12, 13, 14 and 15
    branches:
      include:
        - beverly-hills-ops/matt.oconnor/904176-reactive
```

These are saying:

- Run every hour Monday to Saturday
- Run every hour Tuesday to Wednesday between 0-11 and 16-23 (Therefore don't run between 11-16).

However it is ignoring the second condition....

[image]

[image]

How can I achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft isn't very specific about limitations but keep this in mind.

> **Limits on the number of scheduled runs:**
> There are certain limits on how often you can schedule a pipeline to run. These limits have been put in place to prevent misuse of Azure Pipelines resources, particularly the Microsoft-hosted agents. This limit is around 1000 runs per pipeline per week. ~ [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#limits-on-the-number-of-scheduled-runs)

However I think you just have a cron conflict.
Try this:

```yaml
schedules:
  - cron: '0 */1 * * Mon'
    always: true
    displayName: Run Every hour Monday
    branches:
      include:
        - beverly-hills-ops/matt.oconnor/904176-reactive

  - cron: '0 0-11,16-23 * * Tue-Wed'
    always: true
    displayName: Run Every hour on Tuesday and Wednesday except 12, 13, 14 and 15
    branches:
      include:
        - beverly-hills-ops/matt.oconnor/904176-reactive

  - cron: '0 */1 * * Thu-Sat'
    always: true
    displayName: Run Every hour Thursday to Saturday
    branches:
      include:
        - beverly-hills-ops/matt.oconnor/904176-reactive
```